# Reducing memory use when using rabbitmq in apache camel for large files/messages

Tags: memory, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am sending large zip files of 200-900 MB to camel using curl as binary data. That goes fine to the restlet but when i process the data from restlet to rabbitmq the memory usage goes way up.

I tried commenting out .to(rabbitmq...) and then the problem goes away. It is when i enable the .to(rabbitmq...) endpoint that memory use goes up. I tried to disable the rabbitmq consumer and that did not change things.

It seems the problem is the .to(rabbitmq...) which cause the memory use to go up. I have found that it uses internally a byte[] but converting to InputStream did not do anything. Rabbitmq uses byte[] internally but when done sending to queue it does not release memory.

I have tried streamcaching and also converting body to an InputStream but problem persists.

For now i need a lot of memory and sometimes have to increase heap space top about 4GB for a 900MB Zip file

```java
.to(ExchangePattern.InOnly,"rabbitmq://localhost/myQueue?connectionFactory=#myConnectionFactory&durable=true&queue=myQueue&autoDelete=false&autoAck=false&queueArgsConfigurer=#myQueueArgs")
```

Comment: I dont think a message broker like rabbitmq or others are really intended for storing large binary data in the GBs sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your zip files using an object store like S3, FTP, etc and only pass around URLs to the files via RabbitMQ.

Comment: I ended up doing that. I stored the files on disk and passed filename to rabbit and later polled that file based on what was in rabbit. Memory use is now very low and things run smoothly